# sql input to batch script from console

Tags: mysql, batch-file

I would  like   to write  a simple  windows batch script   which   asks  input for certain valiables  and    run   the sql queries  in the   batch file using those  input .   For example

```
@echo off
mysql "-uroot" -p  -h "xx.xx.xx.xx" "abc"
SET /P ntid= Please  enter the  id of the  user:
select * from tbl_employeedetails where empntid=%ntid%;
```

I would  like  to  request for the  empntid in the console   and then take it  and replace it in the  sql  and then run it.
 When  I run this  I get  the  error:

```
mysql "-uroot" -p  -h "xx.xx.xx.xx" "abc"
Enter password: ********
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/P ntid= Please  enter the  NT id of the  user:
select * from tbl_employeedetail' at line 1
```

I actually   have to  run multiple   queries with  inputs   from user   , which will be prompted in the  console

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you can't do this. the mysql batch mode give you option to run sql file but user interaction is not supported.
take a look at this link to understand mysql batch mode
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/batch-mode.html

but i use a little trick to do that

1. prompt user  for the inputs you need in the sql script.
2. write the sql queries to file
3. run the file with mysql
4. delete the file

this is a sample batch file

```
@echo off
set /p name=Enter Name: 
set /p ts=Enter Ts: 
set /p id=Enter ID: 
@echo update `table1` set `t1`.`name` = "%name%" , `t1`.`ts` = "%ts%" where `t1`.`id` = "%id%";> test.sql
set /p name=Enter Name 2: 
set /p ts=Enter Ts 2: 
set /p id=Enter ID 2 : 
@echo update `t1` set `t1`.`name` = "%name%" , `t1`.`ts` = "%ts%" where `t1`.`id` = "%id%";>> test.sql
set /p name=Enter Name 3: 
set /p ts=Enter Ts 3: 
set /p id=Enter ID 3: 
@echo update `t1` set `t1`.`name` = "%name%" , `t1`.`ts` = "%ts%" where `t1`.`id` = "%id%";>> test.sql
set /p name=Enter Name 4: 
set /p ts=Enter Ts 4: 
set /p id=Enter ID 4: 
@echo update `t1` set `t1`.`name` = "%name%" , `t1`.`ts` = "%ts%" where `t1`.`id` = "%id%";>> test.sql
mysql -uroot -p9272 -hlocalhost test < test.sql
del test.sql
```

hope this could help.